# make number of visits counter in website inner pages

Tags: php, mysql

I am using php to build a website

I need to make number of visits counter in inner pages

I make in database a field to count it and in php I update this field

,it works fine but the problem appear when sharing the link into facebook or any other site the counter is increase it may increase 10 or 20 i.e before sharing it may be 10 and after sharing it become 30

can I solve this problem

Comment: Maybe 20 of your friends visited your website ? Btw, without any piece of code, we won't be able to help you at all...

Comment: no this increase  happens after sharing

Comment: You share -> they visit -> your counter inscreases. QED

Comment: i also think, some websites like facebook request the page too to show a preview of it, maybe look in your access-log.